# fs.readFile always returns content as undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to read a file from disk:

```
exports.getContent = function(filePath, callBack, errorHandler) {
    fs.exists(filePath, function(exists) {
        if (!exists) {
            errorHandler(404);
        } else {
            fs.readFile(filePath, {"encoding": "utf8", "flag": "r"}, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    errorHandler(500, err);
                } else {
                    callBack(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

I have run this through a debugger, finding that the file *does* exist. I reach the `callBack(data)` line, and when inspecting the `data` variable, it is always `undefined`. `err` is `null`.

From [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) I cannot see that this should be possible.

I have also tried to rewrite the code to use `readFileSync`:

```
exports.getContent = function(filePath, callBack, errorHandler) {
    fs.exists(filePath, function(exists) {
        if (!exists) {
            errorHandler(404);
        } else {
            var data;
            try {
                data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, {"encoding": "utf8", "flag": "r"});
            } catch (e) {
                errorHandler(500, e);
            }
            callBack(data);
        }
    });
};
```

... but the results are the same: `err` is `null`, and `data` is `undefined`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have proper permissions to read that file from disk? Perhaps that is the error.

Comment: Jeeeezez ... I'm officially an idiot. Permissions was not the issue, but your suggestion led me to try to open the file in a text editor. And it actually contains the text `undefined`. So when I in my question say that `data` is `undefined`, it was actually `"undefined"`. The file was being read OK all the way.

Comment: Haha...things like that happen. Good luck

Comment: LOL+ This is one of those stories to tell all your programmer friends.

Comment: haha, that was awesome :)